# Scraping Search Results from Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am wondering if there is a way to scrape the search results available at the following website: https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Debates?startDate=1820-01-01&endDate=1911-02-01&searchTerm=%22estimates%22%20%22army%22&house=Commons&partial=False&sortOrder=0

I would like to collect the links provided but I don't see how I would go about doing that given the Javascript provided. I have a very basic knowledge of Javascript though and I imagine there is a way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you just want links from the page:

```js
let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');  // fetches all links

for(var i = 0; i< links.length; i++){
  console.log(links[i].href);       // prints all links
}
```